# Cassandra ReadFailure: code=1300 When Using TTL

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, cassandra, ttl

I am using Cassandra 3.0.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 and have 1G Ram. I have nginx server and nodejs running cql queries.

**When i am using INSERT queries with "USING TTL 300"** parameter Cassandra throws this error message in cqlsh (when i am not using TTL this error never shows):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/cqlsh.py", line 1316, in perform_simple_statement
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip/cassandra-driver-3.0.0-6af642d/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3122, in result
    raise self._final_exception
ReadFailure: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info={'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

and nodejs throws:
    events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

```
RangeError: Trying to access beyond buffer length
    at FrameReader.checkOffset (/var/www/central.network/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/readers.js:119:15)
    at FrameReader.readString (/var/www/central.network/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/readers.js:107:8)
    at FrameReader.readError (/var/www/central.network/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/readers.js:315:22)
    at Parser.parseBody (/var/www/central.network/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:180:66)
    at Parser._transform (/var/www/central.network/node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js:135:10)
    at Parser.Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Parser.Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:307:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:293:5)
    at Parser.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:220:11)
```

and this is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE srv_http.cn56fcde1b44da (
    id timeuuid PRIMARY KEY,
    bn text,
    bv text,
    co text,
    dv text,
    ho text,
    hp text,
    hr text,
    ht text,
    im boolean,
    ip text,
    ir boolean,
    it boolean,
    lt int,
    os text,
    ov text,
    rv boolean,
    sz text,
    ts int,
    ud text,
    ws boolean
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

i searched many hours and tried things but is not solved.

Comment: PS: Error happening after **couple hours**

Comment: 1Gb of RAM is below [recommended](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraHardware) but if its just for testing its fine. Is it a query that makes cqlsh to fail or just trying to start it? On Node.js, when the error is being thrown?